# Find itemId for Walmart Product Lookup API

Tags: walmart-api

I need to retrieve product information from walmart based on a url.

I am currently using their Product Lookup API and need to find the itemId. I thought the ending digits was the itemID but their API docs not return results for this product
https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sportsman-Gasoline-2000W-Portable-Generator/46542330

```
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey={apikey}&ids=46542330
```

results

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 6001,
            "message": "Results not found"
        }
    ]
}
```

It works for some products, like this one
 https://www.walmart.com/ip/Riders-by-Lee-Women-s-Soft-Flannel-Plaid-Shirt/46511109

```
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey={key}&ids=46511109
```

Is there a reason it does not work for all products or is there a better way to get product information based on the url?

Comment: Did you try 554461510? The page says Walmart # 554461510.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for another product:
https://www.walmart.com/ip/4-pack-Progresso-Traditional-Chicken-and-Wild-Rice-Soup-19-oz/742119201

API says result not found